# Using nuget packages from private sources on VISX

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vs-extensibility, vsixmanifest

I have a private Nuget server, and I need to use some of my libraries in my Visual Studio Extension that I am writing. While debugging, the VSIX works fine. But once other developers try to install my extension, the installer can't find some of the nuget packages because it is only looking at nuget.org and not my private server. **So my question is, how can I configure my VSIX to include my private server when pulling the nuget packages while installing itself on other developer's machines?**

Thanks! :)

Comment: Have you tried anything from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43726044/how-to-include-assemblies-from-nuget-packages-in-a-vsix-installer) question?

Comment: Do you add reference to your libraries by 'browse' local directory or 'nuget package manager'? For a vsix project, if we use some libraries in it, Add the reference to nuget manager by adding the private nuget server URL as package sources, then the referenced assemblies will be embedded into the output xx.vsix. So why the installer would look for your libraries, do you add some dependencies about nuget in xx.vsixmanifest file? If I misunderstand anything, please feel free to contact me :)

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I am installing through the nuget package manager. But the packages are not being embedded into the xxx.vsix project. It's giving me a "Could not load file or assembly xxx or one of its dependencies...".

Comment: @Zorthgo I 've just test it. Stepsiew:1. create assembly and sign it(the assembly must be signed) 2. use nuget.exe to package it, and create a nuget server  3. copy the assembly to server, and in vsix, use package manager to install it 4. build it in release and copy the single vsix to remote server 5. the installation works well which indicates the assembly have been embedded into vsix(I write a simple function which will call the method in the assembly, it works well) . So if you create a new vsix project, same issue persists? Not sure if there has some extra prerequisites defined.