# Nuget VsTemplate WizardData Schema

Tags: xml, nuget

So

[VSIX with Project Templates and NuGet Packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620569/vsix-with-project-templates-and-nuget-packages?rq=1)

That post had some great insight.  But due to rather annoying rules I can't comment directly, but if I post this followup question as an "answer" people get peeved, so sorry for the added post but I believe this followup question is relevant

I simply want to ask the people who have been commenting the most about the topic:  where is the "WizardData" xml schema that Nuget's Nuget.VisualStudio.Interop dll uses?

I've seen repository as an attribute on the "packages" element, and id, version, targetFramework, and skipAssemblyReferences as attributes on "package" element.  But where is the schema reference.  I've scanned the source for the Nuget.VisualStudio package, but frankly that would take time to search and find the specific listing (if they even have it there) for the schema.  We're supposed to follow the direction and add xml elements to the "WizardData" element of the vstemplate file but without a schema we're flying blind here.

Thanks
Jaeden "Sifo Dyas" al'Raec Ruiner

Answer (score 0):

There is no schema as far as I can see.

The WizardData is part of the xml namespace that the Visual Studio project template format supports: http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005

The actual contents of the WizardData element can be anything. The Visual Studio template documentation does not specify the contents of it:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171415.aspx

NuGet itself just reads the WizardData element using the XDocument api. I would take a look at the [VsTemplateWizard class](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/38c1939d7f9c97c5dc01e7a7b9a4bf63d283cb6a/src/NuGet.Clients/NuGet.VisualStudio.Implementation/VsTemplateWizard.cs) to see what is supported, or look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/visual-studio-extensibility/visual-studio-templates) on the NuGet documentation web site.

Comment: well, i looked into the documentation at NuGet, but i was looking for more of a spec.  I am well versed in the schema of the VsTemplate file.  However, the WizardData is, as you say a element which can contain any contents that the applied template wizards can access and utilize.  However, what that xml is does not have to conform to the VsTemplate schema.  I was wondering if there was an actual spec sheet for the xml the Nuget.VisualStudio wizard was looking for.  on their documentation site they provide examples, but not a schema spec sheet. thanks, though.